# Prepend or add an Image to the content of a Post

Tags: posts, functions, tags

I've been working with a child theme and functions.php file to add an Image to the posts that have a specific Tag (`Videos` in the code). I was trying to create the function but I have some issues, one is that in the site, when I load a Post with that tag, it crashes, looks like it stays in a loop, and after that I have to manually delete all the repeated images (I just want one) from the posts in the database (PhpMyAdmin)

Could you help me to solve the issue and have working code?

**Important Update**:
 I am using a RSS feed, and I require that Image to be in the feed too (I mean in the posts table database)

Here is my code in `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Prepend image to post if it has a specific tag
 *
 * @param String $content - WP Post Content for display
 *
 * @return String $content - WP Post Content for display
*/ 
function theme_videos_append_image( $content ) {

    global $post;

    // It would be easier if you got this URL from Attachment ID
    $upload_dir_arr     = wp_upload_dir();  // Get upload directory array ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/#user-contributed-notes )
    $static_image_url   = $upload_dir_arr['baseurl'] . '/2017/11/upliftingscroll.jpg';

    // Ensure we are viewing a Post, and it has the Videos tag
    if( has_tag( 'Videos', $post->ID ) ) {

        $has_image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_video_image_added', true );    // Check if our postmeta exists

        // If is does not have our postmeta - add it
        if( empty( $has_image ) ) {

            $image      = sprintf( '<p><img src="%1$s" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></p>', $static_image_url );  // Create image
            $content    = $image . $content;    // prepend image

            // Update post so we don't need to add the image again
            $success = wp_update_post( array(
                'ID'            => $post->ID,
                'post_content'  => $image . $post->post_content,
            ) );

            // If the post updated, create postmeta letting us know later it has the image
            if( false !== $success && !is_wp_error( $success ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_video_image_added', true );
            }

        }

    }

    return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_videos_append_image' );
```

Comment: Why do you update the post content? The function runs and adds the image so no need for updating the post?

Comment: Sorry that i coudn't help on that topic. Would you mind changing the username in your comment (removing my full name)?

Answer (score 1):

Heres a more simple version of your function:

```
<?php

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_videos_append_image' );

    function theme_videos_append_image( $content ) {

        global $post;

        $upload_dir_arr     = wp_upload_dir();
        $static_image_url   = $upload_dir_arr['baseurl'] . '/2017/11/upliftingscroll.jpg';
        $tag = '<p><img src="' . $static_image_url . '" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></p>';

        return has_tag( 'Videos', $post->ID ) ? $tag . $content : $content;

    }

?>
```

Check if that is the most elegant solution for getting the image URL. Seems a bit odd to me.

The loop you've mentioned probably exists because in `wp_update_post` the `the_content` filter also may be applied. So if you want to stick to your solution try adding the post meta first and then updating the post content ... but i don't think this is necessary.

Comment: This way is saved in the database?

Comment: No it isn't. But i don't see why this is necessary?

Comment: Because I am using a RSS feed, and I require that Image to be in the feed too

Comment: Is the the_content filter not applied in this feed?

Comment: No, is not, so that is because I need the image be placed inside the database posts

Comment: Then the 'wp_insert_post_data' or 'content_save_pre' hook may be a better choice over 'the_content'

Comment: add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_videos_append_image' ); would be add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'theme_videos_append_image' ); ??

Comment: @JohannesGandy and I think that would work only with new saved posts

Comment: Use the `the_content_feed` filter.

Comment: @NathanJohnson Wow, now I see it on the feed, I am going to test this now, with that is going to be on all the posts with that tag, right?

Comment: @ricardorios 'wp_insert_post_data' or 'content_save_pre' should run every time the content is modified ... anyway ... yesterday on my way home i thought about this problem again and it seems overly complicated to me for what you want to achieve. If you just want to add an image why not just adding it as normal in the post content or use an shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Extending @GDY solution. You have to also hook to `the_excerpt_rss` filter by doing:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'theme_videos_append_image');

add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_videos_append_image' );

function theme_videos_append_image( $content ) {

        global $post;

        $upload_dir_arr     = wp_upload_dir();
        $static_image_url   = $upload_dir_arr['baseurl'] . '/2017/11/upliftingscroll.jpg';
        $tag = '<p><img src="' . $static_image_url . '" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></p>';

        return has_tag( 'Videos', $post->ID ) ? $tag . $content : $content;

}
```

Comment: would you mind removing my full name. thanks in advance

Comment: @GDY I have update it.

Comment: I appreciate that very much. Thank you.